# Websocket transport is not availiable. flaskscoketIO

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to implement flask-socketIO into my webpage so i began by making a test script to better understand how it works.

whenever I ran my script into the terminal, I would receive this error:

`WARNING in __init__: WebSocket transport not available. Install gevent-websocket for improved performance.`

I then proceeded to enter "conda install gevent-websocket" in the terminal.
everything seemed to be going well until i reran the code. Now nothing appears when i run the code as if something is loading.

Answer (score 2):

Main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import eventlet
    eventlet.monkey_patch()
    import eventlet.wsgi
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 80)), app, log=devnull)
```

flask-socketio

```
    socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True, policy_server=False, async_mode='eventlet', manage_session=False, cors_allowed_origins="*")
    import eventlet
    eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

Requirements:

```
    flask_socketio==5.0.1
    python-engineio==4.0.0
    python-socketio==5.0.4
```

Correct browser api:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
    const socket = io({
        path: '/'+window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]+'/socket.io/',
        transports: [ 'websocket' ] // or [ 'websocket', 'polling' ]
    });
    socket.on('test', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```